# JPA/Hibernate - how to generate ddl for some classes but not others

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, ddl

Is it possible to turn off DDL generation on the class level vs the full application?

I have a reporting app that we have thus far had the setting in `application.properties`

```
jpa.generateDdl=false
```

We effectively have several different views in this app that populate java objects annotated with `@Entity`.  This works great.

But now we want to add other objects which we DO want to persist.

If I switch on `jpa.generateDdl=true`, then it will generate tables for these views, which we want to avoid.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening, while still allowing other objects to persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not possible.

As written in the Hibernate documentation you shouldn't relay on the feature for production applications.

> Although the automatic schema generation is very useful for testing
> and prototyping purposes, in a production environment, it’s much more
> flexible to manage the schema using incremental migration scripts.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation

I would recommend to use Liquibase or Flyway to use for database migrations.